# Desativar guias de indentação verticais VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Comecei a usar recentemente  o Vscode e estou tentando configurar ele a meu gosto. Mas não estou encontrado como desativar as linhas em "Vertical" que marcam os elementos (pais e filhos) junto com a indentação.

[image: Assim como na imagem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Abra o menu das preferências - a `roda dentada` no canto inferior esquerdo;
2. Seleccione `Settings`;
3. Acrescente a entrada `"editor.renderIndentGuides": false` às suas definições.

---

Já agora, se a sua ideia é personalizar a sua instalação do VS Code recomendava dar uma vista de olhos as *default settings* aí disponíveis pois estão super bem documentadas e dar para ter uma ideia de tudo o que dá para personalizar no VS Code.

Comment: Muito obrigado :D